# VC post grid doesnt display current site

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I made a post grid that works like a navigation with the header-image. Only problem is I can't display the site the grid is used. 
I can add it in **List of ID's** but it doesnt display it in the front-end.

Comment: Could you add some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: I use the Visual Composer Post Grid for Wordpress. Didnt code anything. I use as Data-Source the "List of IDs"-option and added the sites i want in the grid. It shows every site but not the site im currently using (so the site the post grid is on). I use a simple custom grid template but i doubt that thats the problem.